# jquery nested $.each show and hide element(div) based on parameter

Tags: jquery

I try to accomplish that when I click on link only some of 'div' element with id show and other remain hide.

arrValues can only contain 0 and 1 values and
0 elementId need to be hide  = .css('display', 'none')
1 elementId need to be shown = .css('display', 'block')

> 

```
        <!-- Box 1 -->
        <div id="panelSomeName1" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#1">Box 1</a></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Box 2 -->
        <div id="panelSomeName2" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#2">Box 2</a></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Box 3 -->
        <div id="panelSomeName3" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#3">Box 3</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Box 4 -->
        <div id="panelSomeName4" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#4">Box 4</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Box 5 -->
        <div id="panelSomeName5" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#5">Box 5</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Box 6 -->
        <div id="panelSomeName6" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#6">Box 6</a></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    content

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Box 7 Box -->
        <div id="panelSomeName7" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#7">Box 7</a></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="7" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Box 8 -->
        <div id="panelSomeName8" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#8">Box 8</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="mb8" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
  $('#showOptions').on("click", function (e) {
```

`var arrValues = '11110001'.split('');

  $.each(arrValues, function (intIndex, objValue) {

      $("#panelBoxOptions").children("div").each( function () {
       var _id = "#" + $(this).attr("id");

       console.log(intIndex +" " +_id + " " + objValue);

       var dsplHide = (objValue != 0 ) ? $(_id).css('display', 'block') : $(_id).css('display', 'none');


        });
  });

     $('#panelBoxOptions').css('display', 'block');`

});

So which is the correct nested structure that I have to follow to solve this problem?

Thank you.

[I make a working example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/murgulj/vdzpkthd/36/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you had a loop (`each`) inside of another loop (hence so many lines showing up in the console log instead of just the eight), and that seemed to cause all the values to go back to 1. [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vdzpkthd/37/) seems to work by removing the part that looped over arrValues and instead asking if intIndex of the current div is 1 or 0 in arrValues. The relevant change:

```
// ....
var arrValues = '11110001'.split('');  
$("#panelBoxOptions").children("div").each( function (intIndex) {
  var _id = "#" + $(this).attr("id");
  var whichValue = arrValues[intIndex];
  var dsplHide = (whichValue != 0 ) ? $(_id).css('display', 'block') : $(_id).css('display', 'none');  
}); 
// ....
```

Comment: I think in my fiddle I changed some of the ID values, because they started with numbers, which they're not supposed to. I don't know if that affected the functionality, but thought I should mention it just in case.

Comment: This make sense, I was complicated too much. This work like a charm. Thank you Max